# Object disappearing from mongoose data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

programmers. I am currently attempting to delete an Object from inside an Object in my data.
My schema is as follows:

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    currentEmployment: { type: Object },
    employmentHistory: [
        {
            department: { type: String },
            lastPosition: { type: String },
            joinDate: { type: Number },
            leaveDate: { type: Number },
            punishmentHistory: [
                {
                    type: { type: String },
                    reason: { type: String },
                    date: { type: Number }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
});
```

Now, I am currently trying to delete the 'Police' Object from inside the "currentEmployment" object. My current data is the following:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId('65e1be295d4d201b8aa902d4'),
  userId: '1',
  employmentHistory: [],
  currentEmployment: {
    'Police': {
      position: 'Captain',
      joinDate: 1709306734,
      punishmentHistory: []
    }
  }
  __v: 0
}
```

I attempted to use the following code to accomplish this:

```
data.currentEmployment['Police'] = undefined;
console.log(data);
await data.save();
```

The `console.log(data);` statement printed this:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId('65e1f36e4317612bf1266787'),
  userId: '1',
  employmentHistory: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

Why is the entire "currentEmployment" object getting deleted from my data?

Comment: try with null instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to note here. Firstly, it is better to handle this in one query using `$unset` like so:

```js
const data = await Employee.findOneAndUpdate({
    userId: '1',
},{
    $unset: {
        "currentEmployment.Police": ""
    }
},{new: true});
```

This will set `currentEmployment` to an empty object.

Secondly however, you will notice that `currentEmployment` does not show up as an empty object when you query that document. You would need to use mongosh or Compass and query the collection, then you will see it.

With mongoose an empty object is not normally saved to a document due to the `minimize: true` default settings so when you return the document from a query `currentEmployment` won't show.

To work around that you need to add the `toJSON: { minimize: false }` option to your schema which tells mongoose not to minimize those empty objects when you convert to JSON. You would add this option like so:

```js
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    //...
    //...
}, { 
    toJSON: { minimize: false } 
});
```